# Why use blocks\grid instead of for-loop?

Tags: c++, c, performance, cuda

Why use:

```
kernel<<<512, 512>>>( ); //somewhere
__device__ void kernel( ) {
    Code( );
}
```

Rather than:

```
kernel<<<1, 512>>>( 512 ); //somewhere
__device__ void kernel( int n ) {
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i ) {
        Code( );
    }
}
```

NOTE: I don't have CUDA GPU yet to check it.

Is the first somehow faster? GPU Cores can't handle long-running threads or loses it's speed while running longer?

I guess the second (for-loop) is better when the number of the desired iteration are not aligned to the number of thread. (We can change the `n` variable in the last thread\core)

Comment: The GPU is a latency hiding machine. The more work you *expose*, the better job it can do of hiding latency, which means it gets the work done faster, per unit work.  `<<<512,512>>>` does two things: 1. it exposes much more parallelism, i.e. the possibility for more work available to hide latency and 2. it allows multiple SMs on the GPU to be used. `<<<1,512>>>` consists of only one threadblock, which means that only one SM can be used. This topic is the subject of an [hour-long class](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3466-Programming-Guidelines-GPU-Architecture.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very idea of CUDA is that you should do parallel work in parallel. The entire execution architecture is designed to make that fast. Anything which is truly *parallel*, i.e. where all parallel pieces of the logic execute the exact same logic in lockstep, are better done by executing the same instructions on many, many cores at once, rather than executing many instructions with complicated branching and looping on one core.

I recommend you read the extensive documentation published about CUDA by Nvidia, with special attention to warps, bank conflicts, local memory, branching, etc. Programming for GPU is not at all trivial, and like with any kind of concurrent programming, you should expect the process to be painful and expensive *unless* you have both an extremely good reason to be concurrent and also understand lots of the low-level details very well.

Comment: But the first one won't parallize my code more, because I choose 512 cores and not more. Can you expand on the `complicated branching` part? Maybe it will help.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: Hm, read up on blocks and how they get scheduled. The actual scheduling unit is a warp, which is much smaller, so that isn't actually an issue.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: The important limit that you need to care about is the number of threads per block. Each block must fit onto the GPU. For example, if your block size is 1024 (e.g. 32*32), and you have 1536 cores, then you can only schedule one block at a time. But you can have an arbitrary number of blocks in total.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how threads get assigned to GPU execution resources.
Whole blocks get distributed among the streaming multiprocessors on the GPU. If you launched a grid with a single block, your kernel would run on one SM. This would be fine on a very small GPU with a single SM like the Tegra K1, but on most GPUs, which have multiple SMs (like the 24 on a GTX Titan X), you'd be wasting a considerable amount of resources.